# Implementing a Max algorithm that is O(1)

Tags: performance, big-o

I am asked to implement a simple algorithm to find the maximum number in a list with one important condition. The algorithm should be O(1). So I wrote this:

```
int max = Int32.MinValue;
foreach (int item in _items)
{
    if (item.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        max = item;
}

return max;
```

As some pointed in the comment section this is O(N). But how can you find the maximum number in a list with an algorithm that is O(1). Because to me it seems that you have to iterate all the arrays items to find the max number. Is this even possible?

Comment: What?! Who asked you to find the maximum element of a list in constant time? Is the list supposed to be sorted?

Comment: What?? This is O(N) not O(1). Please look up how the notation works somewhere.

Comment: Post edit, what you are trying to do is information-theory impossible unless you know more about the list's contents (such as knowing ahead of time that it is sorted).  If you think about it, the mere act of looking at every value to do comparisons with is O(n), so any attempt to do it faster, like O(1) would literally have to arrive at the right answer without looking at all of the values.  That'll be one lucky algorithm!

Comment: Unless your array is sorted, you can't find the "max" with O(1) constant time.

Comment: One solution that comes to my mind is to have a separate sorted list. Whenever an item is added or deleted from the list, the sorted list get updated as well. However this will increase Big O notation of add method to O(2) which is not allowed.

Comment: @Dane O(2) is just a confusing way to say O(1). What you're proposing (adding to a sorted list) would be O(log n) though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After taking into account your original question as well as your comments (and, I suppose, some inference on my part), your requirements are as follows:

1. A list-like data structure with
2. O(1) random access
3. O(1) insertion at the end (amortized)
4. O(1) deletion at the end (amortized)
5. O(1) max

The most straight-forward solution (keeping track of the max element on insertion) fails requirement 4 as you'd need to recalculate the max on deletion. So can we adjust it to solve this problem?

Yes, we can! Instead of just keeping track of the total maximum, we keep track of the maximum up to i for all indices i. So every time we append to the list, we add an entry to the list that contains the value as well as the new maximum. So to get the total maximum, we take the maximum at the last index. To delete the last element, we simply remove the last entry. And to get an element at index i, we take the entry at index i and return its value. So as long as the underlying data structure performs these operations in (amortized) O(1) (which, say, an ArrayList would), so do we.

Comment: What will happen if we have a list of size 3, {9,8,7} and we remove 9? Wouldn't we also need to change the max for both 8 and 7 nodes?

Comment: @IshayPeled My solution supports ammortized O(1) anywhere where an ArrayList does. Deleting at the beginning of an ArrayList is O(n) anyway, so that's unrelated to the max (and if we used a linked list instead, random access would be O(i)).

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. Except I have the same problem that Ishay mentioned. If we want to delete an element in the middle of list, we need to recalculate the max for all elements from the start to the end. Am I right or I am missing something? @sepp2k

Comment: @Dane What exactly *are* your requirements? If you want a list data structure where you have O(1) random access and O(1) deletion at arbitrary indices, you're asking for the impossible even without considering the max function.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. As I know deletion in a linked list is O(1), because you simply delete the node and connect the node before to the node after. An example would be Singly Linked List. @sepp2k

Comment: @Dane Deletion in a linked list is O(1) if you have an iterator to the deleted item - it's O(n) if you only have the index. More importantly random access in a linked list is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Like the commenters said, it is impossible unless you maintain a max variable and update it on each insert operation:

```
Insert(element)  
    If element > max  
        max = element  
    (Rest of insertion code)
```

That way you can return max in O(1) when asked

[EDIT]
If I understand your limitations correctly, you want a solution that does:
O(1) - Insertion
O(1) - Deletion
O(1) - Get max
O(1) - Retrieve

Not sure that such an algorithm exists, but following this thread to see if I can learn something new (;

Answer (score 0):

The Heap data structure might be what you are looking for. The basic version has find max O(1), and insert and delete O(log N). The Fibonacci heap has insert O(1) as well. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

Answer (score -1):

You can maintain a variable containing the highest value in the list.  As you insert/delete, you keep track of that value.

Then your max function can be O(1):

```
def max(): return max_value
```

This adds work on insert/delete, but meets your specified requirement that max() runs in constant time.

Comment: Very interesting solution. However, it will not meet another requirement that I have. Insert and delete should be O(1) too. If an items deleted from the list, the program have to go through all remaining items to find the minimum number, therefore it will not be O(1). Is there a workaround for this limitation?

Comment: Dane, maybe if you stored arrays sorted by value ascending and value descending, so you're now storing three arrays for the values, so you're storing three times as much space. However, when you delete an item, you can just remove it from the top of one of the lists, grab the next item down which you know is the next highest, and then remove the bottom one from the final list. So you're using more memory but it should now be O(1)